# Do one thing with an object, do another thing with a list of objects

Tags: c#, generic-collections

I'd like to write a function that takes one input parameter, then:

- if it's a list of objects, does one thing, but
- if it's a single object, does another thing.

I'm imagining this function to look like this:

```
 void DoSomething(object x) {
      if (x is List) { Swizzle(x); }
      else { Wibble(x); }
 }
```

For various reasons, it would be best to do this all inside a single function.

(The `List` I'm using is the standard one found in `System.Collections.Generic`.)

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. This is actually valid C#, assuming the existence of `Swizzle` and `Wibble`. What's your question?

Comment: @JeroenMostert not valid because there is no such type as List. (non-generic)

Comment: The example code fails on the expression `x is List`.  `List` isn't really a type you can use, it has to be `List<`something`>`.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry about that. There is a non-generic list type, of course, but it's `ArrayList`, and `List<T>` doesn't inherit from it (obviously). But `List<T>` is an `IList` and an `IEnumerable`, though.

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or something that's supposed to have practical value? Because practically speaking, you're much better off writing `DoSomething<T>(List<T> objects)` and then check if `objects.Count == 1` if you really must do something special for a single value. Or you can simply write two (overloaded) functions: `DoSomething<T>(List<T> objects)` and `DoSomething<T>(T object)`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, let's treat it as an academic exercise.

Answer (score 3):

So you need to cast it to a List

Without attempting reflection why not just use function overloading:

```
void DoSomething<T>(List<T> aList)
{
    // this is Swizzle
}

void DoSomething(object obj)
{
    // this is Wibble
}
```

If you don't know the type at compile time, and hence function overloading does not work, you can use reflection

```
    public class Foo
    {
        private void Swizzle<T>(List<T> list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sizzle");
        }

        private void Wibble(object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wibble");
        }

        public void DoSomething(object o)
        {
             var ot = o.GetType();
             if (ot.IsGenericType && ot.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
             {
                 this.GetType().GetMethod("Swizzle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).MakeGenericMethod(ot.GetGenericArguments()[0])
                     .Invoke(this, new object[] { o });
             }
             else
                 this.Wibble(o);
        }
    }


// Then usage
 var foo = new Foo();
 foo.DoSomething(new List<int>());
 foo.DoSomething(new object());
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is an academic exercise then you can abuse the runtime type resolution.

```
void DoSomething(object x)
{
    Call((dynamic) x);
}

void Call(IList items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Swizzle");
}

void Call(object item)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Wibble");
}
```

Example:

```
DoSomething(new object[] { });     // Swizzle
DoSomething(new List<object> { }); // Swizzle
DoSomething(new List<int> { });    // Swizzle
DoSomething(1);                    // Wibble
DoSomething(new object());         // Wibble
```

Comment: This will work just as well with `Call<T>(List<T> items)`, by the way, to stay in the constraints of the question. (Of course then the array no longer matches.) `IList<object>` is no better than `IList`; `IEnumerable<T>` would be better than either in terms of generality.

Comment: Like it - Forgot about dynamic typing.  This should probably be the answer for .NET versions that support it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reflection` to see if it's `List<T>`

```
var type = x.GetType();
if(type.IsGenericType &&
   type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

Or, if you wanna know if it's a collection in general, you can try checking if it's `IList`:

```
if(x is IList)
```

Comment: @Joe yes you need to make sure the type is generic before calling that method. I updated the code accordingly